# Facing Error - php artisan serve not working in Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I am trying to view my website on localhost but when i run php artisan serve command I'm facing this error.

> In Connection.php line 664:
> SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'imperial_main'@'localhost' (using password: NO) (SQL: selec
> t * from `redirections` where `from` = http://127.0.0.1/ limit 1)
> In Exception.php line 18:
> SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'imperial_main'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
> In PDOConnection.php line 40:
> SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'imperial_main'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
> PS D:\xampp7.1.3\htdocs\backup-imperialride_ae>

**My .env file**

```
APP_NAME=Laravel
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY==
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_URL=http://localhost

LOG_CHANNEL=stack

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=test
DB_USERNAME=test
DB_PASSWORD=8mVNzfHR~*@s

BROADCAST_DRIVER=log
CACHE_DRIVER=file
QUEUE_CONNECTION=sync
SESSION_DRIVER=file
SESSION_LIFETIME=120

REDIS_HOST=127.0.0.1
REDIS_PASSWORD=null
REDIS_PORT=6379
```

**My database**

[image: img]

I want to view my website on localhost. plz, help me to figure out this problem and guide me on how can i solve this. I'll be very thankful to you

Answer (score -1):

if you want to view your website on your local machine then you have to provide the database name in your .env file and the DB_username

```
APP_NAME=Laravel
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY==
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_URL=http://localhost

LOG_CHANNEL=stack

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=test  //Your Database name
DB_USERNAME=test //By Default it should be root
DB_PASSWORD=8mVNzfHR~*@s //no need for password you can keep it blank

BROADCAST_DRIVER=log
CACHE_DRIVER=file
QUEUE_CONNECTION=sync
SESSION_DRIVER=file
SESSION_LIFETIME=120

REDIS_HOST=127.0.0.1
REDIS_PASSWORD=null
REDIS_PORT=6379
```